# Cloned mac not work with networkmanager in 64bit Ubuntu, And I use USB Wireless Card RT3070

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I set a different mac address in the networkmanager, but it keep the old mac address.

However, change mac work with type `ifconfig hw ether ***`, but it's not that I want:

[image]

I found this in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
May 19 07:14:22 j-QTH6 NetworkManager[1244]: <info> (wlan1): taking down device.
May 19 07:14:22 j-QTH6 NetworkManager[1244]: <warn> (wlan1): failed to change interface MAC address
May 19 07:14:22 j-QTH6 NetworkManager[1244]: <warn> (wlan1): failed to set MAC address to A8:35:D7:D2:4F:1A
May 19 07:14:23 j-QTH6 NetworkManager[1244]: <info> Activation (wlan1) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) scheduled...
May 19 07:14:23 j-QTH6 NetworkManager[1244]: <info> Activation (wlan1) Stage 1 of 5 (Device Prepare) complete.
```

I also try to change another mac, still not work.

Then I tried to do the same thing in ubuntu13.04-amd64, xubuntu13.04-amd64 and ubuntu12.04LTS-amd64. I found it only work in 12.04LTS.

So is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal), `macchanger --help`, among other things, it shows me:

```
GNU MAC Changer
Usage: macchanger [options] device

  ...
  -m,  --mac=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
       --mac XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  Set the MAC XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

So, `macchanger` is a good Linux utility for changing the MAC address for network interfaces.

Here is how I changed my MAC:

[image: macchanger]

To use `macchanger` and `airmon-ng`, I think you need to have installed `aircrack-ng`. To install it, run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng
```